# How to include image or diagrams in this page?

Tags: support, images

Since I am new to this forum,  I have not much idea about framing the questions of right sort to this group? Moreover,  I am unable to upload  images in this page along with the question text. As I am trying to upload image from Android phone, I am unable to find enough option to include pictures here.  Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you're on an Android phone, are you using the Stack Exchange *app*? Or the mobile website? (or the desktop website?)

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not "a forum". They are sites for Questions and Answers.

Comment: If you put a link then people will come and inline that link in no time. Unless they havce some problems with the source.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't actually have the Android app, but I can tell you how to upload an image with images I found on MSE (click on an image to be taken to its source).

When you're in the app, you should see something like this:

[image]

There are several icons in the toolbar. The one you want is the camera icon, which will let you upload an image.

You then select an image:

[image]

Your image will need to be in an accepted file format. For example, PNG and JPEG are accepted formats, SVG is not.

And it will be inserted into your post. Your image must be under 2MB otherwise you will get a [confusing error message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305860/323179) and your image will not be inserted.

---

Note: On some sites (but not this one), users with less than 10 rep will [not be able to inline an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259562/323179) (it will need to be a link).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think new members can post images.

However, in any case, you can upload your image to imgur(dot)com, then you can simply add the link to your question. Another member will likely help edit your question by inserting the actual image for you.

Comment: New users can post images here (it's different on other SE sites, but I believe they can post up to 3 here)

Comment: @Cai perhaps it has something to do with trying to do it from an Android phone.  I've seen several questions here from new users who apparently don't seem to be able to post images.

Comment: Oh hold on... you said "I don't think new members *can't* post images". So you're saying new users can post images? Your double negative confused me

Comment: @Cai oops, I think I meant "can". Fixed!